# How to best to install vinyl floor around the base of banister?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I am planning to install a vinyl floor in a large portion of the main floor of my home. What baffles me is how to best install the vinyl when it covers the floor around the large banisters going upstairs. Currently, the tired and damaged wood floor goes right up against the wood banister. I understand that vinyl floor requires an expansion gap.

- Should I under cut and slide the vinyl under?
- Should I leave an expansion gap and use quarter round?
- Should I use several small and precisely cut shoe molding?

Design notes:

- Honey oak banister will be painted white
- Carpet will be installed on the stairs

[image]

Comment: Are you removing the existing wood strip flooring? If not, are you putting something between it and the vinyl flooring? If not, you'll see & feel every one of those gaps between the strips! Any of your 3 solutions will work, which one is "best" is subject to opinion (and thus off-topic by default), but depends on your skills and willingness to put effort in.

Comment: That's called a "newel post", FYI. Bannister would be an entire railing assembly.

Comment: Thanks @FreeMan I will be removing the existing wood floor. I'm planning on using an underlayment as well. It's a plyboard subfloor with a basement under.

Answer (score 1):

Newel posts aren't usually undercut. I would fit your flooring around it and install base shoe, mitered at the corners.

Comment: You're welcome. Please [take the tour](http://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn what to do next.